# Ionic 5 - Read file from Asset folder

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a file in `asset/files/myFile`. I want to read it in a component.

In Ionic 3 i do : `this.http.get("assets/files/Filename")`

In Ionic 5 i have an error because the request search : `http://localhost/assets/files/Filename`

What's wrong ?
Thanks !

EDIT : I use HttpClientModule

Comment: Http isn't for accessing resources via that protocol. What kind of file is it?

Comment: @AluanHaddad a simple text file ;)

Comment: Load it with `import file from 'file.txt';`, bundling it. You will need to add `declare module '*.txt';` somewhere. Webpack (what is doing all the work) will load the file for you

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Articles } from "src/assets/devArticles/articles.json";
```

Where json looks like this:

```
 {
   "Articles": [{
   "title": "What does Healthy Software look like?",
   "url": "https://dev.to/jwp/what-does-healthy-software-look-like-ad2"
},
```

Or this:

```
import data from "src/assets/devArticles/file.json"
```

Or this in node:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Accessing properties of a json file as if they were named exports relies on sketchy loader interop when it works at all. Import it as the `default`: `import data from "file.json"` and reference the property as `data.Articles`

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying on 'default: import data' it looks like a object Key Vaue pair but where?.  The reason I ask is that what I posted worked for me.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The correct import is `import data from "src/assets/devArticles/file.json"`, and you have that,  but you also have `import { Articles } from "src/assets/devArticles/articles.json"` which is highly problematic. You can't pick properties off of the single object exported by a module as if they were named imports. When you import a JSON file as if it were a module, a module is actually synthesized by the loader, because JSON files are not modules. That module looks like `export default JSON.parse("{\"Articles\": whatever}")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this 😜

This is for a json, make the changes as convenient

```js
fetch('/assets/your_file')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to get an asset though. Use a normal import and webpack will handle getting the file from the correct location at runtime.

Comment: You are right, but everyone has their own way of programming and this is their path. thanks for the comment